# Adding another view below a collection view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uicollectionview

How do I implement a screen in iOS6 (iphone) where top half of the screen is a collection view (horizontally scrollable) and the bottom half is other view that is not scrollable?  These two view are not necessarily linked.

(BTW, I already have the horizontal scrolling working separately).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using containment features in view controller - addChildViewController.  Watch the 2012 WWDC video on Evolution of View Controller for more information.